# Checking if a tag is on the screen

Tags: javascript, dom

This function receives an `HTMLElement` as an argument and returns `true` if the tag is on the screen and `false` otherwise.

```
function isTagVisible(tag) {
    var box;

    box = tag.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (box.left > 0) {
        if (box.left >= window.innerWidth) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (box.right <= 0) {
        return false;
    }

    if (box.top > 0) {
        if (box.top >= window.innerHeight) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (box.bottom <= 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> if (box.left > 0) {
>     if (box.left >= window.innerWidth) {
>         return false;
>     }
> }
> ```

This seems a little redundant: the `innerWidth` is going to be greater than 0, so why do you need to conditionals?

Simply remove the outer one.

---

Your conditions are fairly short. Consider combining them:

```
if (box.right <= 0 || box.bottom <= 0) {
    return false;
}

if (box.left >= window.innerWidth || box.top >= window.innerHeight) {
    return false;
}
```

---

There isn't much more to say about your code, but I have an idea for future improvement: right now, your code will say `true` even if the element is partially hidden on the screen. How do you plan on handling this?

Comment: I intended to return `true` even when the element is partially hidden. Thanks for your feedback.